# Using browserify on file with require('mongodb') causes TypeError: dns.resolveSrv is not a function

Tags: javascript, mongodb, browser, browserify

I am working on a simple chrome extension that will allow me to write, get and delete URL's from an to a DB.
I decided to use MongoDB and wrote the functions in JS file called popup.js. and they work OK from the IDE.

Because it will run from the browser i used Browserify for the require('mongodb').

I used  `browserify popup.js -o bundle.js`
and when running the bundle.js file i get `TypeError: dns.resolveSrv is not a function`  (when running from both the ide and the browser)
it happend when it tries connecting to the client.

what can i do to avoid this issue?

Thanks in advance.

popup.js :

```
const {MongoClient} = require('mongodb');

async function checkURL(client , URL){
    const result = await client.db("url-uploader").collection("urls").findOne({URL: URL})
    return !(result===null)
}


async function uploadURL(){
    const uri = {myURI};
    const client = new MongoClient(uri, {useUnifiedTopology: true});
    try {
        await client.connect();
        let newURL = 'www.b.com'//tab.url
        if (!await checkURL(client, newURL)) {
            const result = await client.db("url-uploader").collection("urls").insertOne({URL: newURL})
        }
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
    } finally {
        await client.close();
    }
}

async function removeURL(){
    const uri = {myURI};
    const client = new MongoClient(uri , {useUnifiedTopology: true});
    try {
        await client.connect();
        let oldURL = "www.blabla.com" //tab.url
        const result = await client.db("url-uploader").collection("urls").deleteOne({URL: oldURL})
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
    } finally {
        await client.close();
    }
}
```

and this is the part in bundle.js that gets the error:

```
_poll() {
    const generation = this.generation;
    dns.resolveSrv(this.srvAddress, (err, srvRecords) => {
      if (generation !== this.generation) {
        return;
      }

      if (err) {
        this.failure('DNS error', err);
        return;
      }

      const finalAddresses = [];
      srvRecords.forEach(record => {
        if (matchesParentDomain(record.name, this.srvHost)) {
          finalAddresses.push(record);
        } else {
          this.parentDomainMismatch(record);
        }
      });

      if (!finalAddresses.length) {
        this.failure('No valid addresses found at host');
        return;
      }

      this.success(finalAddresses);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Where did you define `resolveSrv` ? You are clearly using `dns`. not sure what that is and where you have defined it, but I don't see a reference to it's definition. Can you provide more details?

Comment: it should be  included in the mongodb module according to the documentation: https://nodejs.org/api/dns.html#dns_dns_resolvesrv_hostname_callback
Browserify was suppose to pack it in my code

Comment: You didn't import `dns` module. Simply define it using `const dns = require('dns');`?

Comment: i tried adding it to the popup.js file but it had no effect. i think browserify suppose to add all necessery subModules to the bundle on its own.